# Is the set of all continuous maps from a set $M$ to a set $N$ a set?

Tags: set-theory

I am following course on topology that is kind of lack luster (not made for mathematicians). The course starts off with predicate logic and axiomatic set theory (ZFC). Now, I reached a point where the author defined the partition of unity and used the set of all continuous functions between 2 sets. But at the starts of the course, we learned about the principle of restricted comperhension, which requires us to state a set, say $D$, in order for $\{\phi\in D|\phi:M\rightarrow N\,continuous\}$ to be a set. So, my question is: in what set are the maps from $M$ to $N$ found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In logic, a map from a set $M$ to a set $N$ is usually defined as a relation from $M$ to $N$. And a relation is a subset of $M \times N$.

Therefore, the set you're looking for is a subset of $\mathcal P(M \times N)$.

Answer (score 2):

A function $M\to N$ is usually defined as a relation, i.e. a subset of $M\times N$ (not every such relation is a function, but any function is such a relation). Which is to say a function $M\to N$ is an element of the power set $P(M\times N)$, so that works as your $D$.